# `devtools::load_all(".")` versus `library()`

Tags: r, devtools

I am writing a package called Posterior Bootstrap. If I do `R CMD build` and enter an R session:

```
> library("PosteriorBootstrap")
> PosteriorBootstrap::stick_breaking(1)
Error: 'stick_breaking' is not an exported object from 'namespace:PosteriorBootstrap'
```

even though the function is exported, as shown in `NAMESPACE`:

```
$ cat PosteriorBootstrap/NAMESPACE 
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export(anpl)
export(stick_breaking)
importFrom(Rcpp,cpp_object_initializer)
```

The loaded package is showing old functions that I exported in a previous version and not the most recent ones.

If I change directory into the package and replace the `library` call with `devtools::load_all(".")`, it works:

```
> devtools::load_all(".")
Loading PosteriorBootstrap
Loading required package: Rcpp
...
> PosteriorBootstrap::stick_breaking
function(concentration = 1,
...
)
```

How can I load the package I am working on without `devtools`?

Comment: Are you sure you have the most recent version of your package installed in your library? If you change the source code, you'd normally have to rebuild the tarball and run `install.packages()`. It's a bit of a pain which is why many people prefer to use `devtool` because it makes loading work-in-progress packages much easier.

Comment: Yes, I think that is the problem. I run `install.packages("PosteriorBootstrap", repos=NULL, type="source")` inside `R` from the parent directory, `library` again, and it still uses the old version.

Comment: You would need to use R CMD BUILD to package your library and then call install.packages on the created tar ball. Also make sure to unload any currently attached versions before attaching again. But really I would just recommend using devtools.

Comment: The docs for `load_all` spell out some of the advantages during development: https://devtools.r-lib.org/reference/load_all.html

Comment: @camille I could not see from that documentation nor from the source code of `pkgload::load_all` what I could differently in the scenario without `devtools`.

Comment: Like mentioned above and like you said might be one problem, `load_all` will load what's currently in your package code, not what's in the most recent compiled and installed version. It also loads objects that aren't exported by your package, which is handy for editing functions and data that won't be exported. The part in the docs about shims is over my head though